# Which Map app can I use?

Tags: apps, google, maps, here, blu-win-hd

I used before Google Maps on Android, now I have Windows phone (BLU Win HD LTE) and can't find map app, which is convenient and reliable.

Google Maps is't available for Windows phone, at least I couldn't find it.

Microsoft Maps is okay, but they don't have navigation, so I need install additional navigation app. I tried gMaps and Waze, but didn't like them.

I heard that Here Maps and Here Drive+ are very good, but I can't find them in Widows Store.

Are Here apps still available? If not which Map app can I use, which is similar to Google Maps?

Comment: I would've expected Here Drive to be preinstalled, as it was [made available to all Windows Phone 8.1 users](http://360.here.com/2014/04/02/free-drive-everyone-windows-phone-8-1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows mobile 10 the default maps app is all you need.
It uses the downloaded offline maps and has turn by turn voice guidance without the need of internet connection and by using GPS detection just like the Here app.
Imagine the Nokia Here Drive+ part of the default preinstalled microsoft maps app. Now integrated as part of the OS itself to let you worry about one less app!
In case of having windows 8.x on your phone, you could upgrade to 10 insider or wait for the soon to be released 10 final or get the Here Drive+ Maps from the store. Mind you that Drive is only the navigation app and you will still need to use the default maps app or the Nokia Maps app for simple map viewing and usage.

Comment: okay, maybe I'll wait for Windows 10. Or should I try insider? Is it stable enough?

Comment: Having just upgraded to the latest (Fast track) Insider build last night, it's very usable. There are a few bugs that I've seen, usually involving things like the Messaging app crashing after I send a MMS, but the message goes through and I can just re-launch the app. I'm on a Lumia 1520, which is a more powerful but older phone than the Win HD.

Comment: Exactly. Latest Insider build is the RTM version and I am on an underspec'd  Lumia 925 with the old Snapdragon processor and performance is not an issue. Still battery drains a little more and animations may get a little choppy at times but nothing major and in general ready to have as an everyday guide. You can always rollback to 8.1 whenever you feel like it so I would suggest to give it a try.

Comment: at last made upgrade to Windows 10. But I don't like this windows map, Gooole Map is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the apps on your phone by going through these store links:

[Here Drive+](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/app/9wzdncrfhw6c)

[Here Maps](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/store/apps/app/9wzdncrfhw6b)

Comment: I get the following on this page: This app is not available for your device. Maybe it works only on Windows 10?